# SQL Server 2014 trying to create an indexed view however I'm getting the following error

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, view

```
SELECT 
     fcb.PharmacyKey  as PharmID 
    ,fcb.DateKeY as UploadDate
    ,fcb.RecordSource as Description
    ,fcb.Amount
FROM 
    dbo.FactCheckBookData fcb
WHERE 
    fcb.RecordSource in ('BeginningBalance')
    AND convert(datetime, left(fcb.DateKey, 8),101) =  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Convert(varchar(8), getdate(), 112)), 0)
```

Error:

> Cannot create index on view 'dbo.view' because the view uses an
>   implicit conversion from string to datetime or smalldatetime. Use an
>   explicit CONVERT with a deterministic style value.

Comment: `Convert(varchar(8),getdate(),112)`, why?, you should just use `GETDATE()`

Comment: I need the view to filter to the first day of the month, hence why getdate() wouldn't work.

Comment: @Lamak is saying it's not necessary to convert the date in a `DATEDIFF` function (e.g. just write `DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())`), but I doubt this is what is causing your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one day to end of previous month.

```
SELECT 
     fcb.PharmacyKey  as PharmID 
    ,fcb.DateKeY as UploadDate
    ,fcb.RecordSource as Description
    ,fcb.Amount
FROM dbo.FactCheckBookData fcb
WHERE fcb.RecordSource in ('BeginningBalance')
AND convert(datetime,left(fcb.DateKey,8),101) =  
    DateAdd (Day, 1, EOMONTH(getdate(), -1))
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, to find the first day of the month, you can use

```
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()),0)
```

However, if you change your code, the error will change to

```
Cannot create index on view 'someView'. The function 'getdate' yields nondeterministic results. Use a deterministic system function, or modify the user-defined function to return deterministic results.
```

Because `GETDATE()` is non-deterministic and therefore cannot be used in an indexed view.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms191432.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091.aspx